# Can we access sharepoint news feed with active directory authentication?

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to create a mobile application using cordova to access outlook services and sharepoint news feed. 
I managed to access outlook services with ADAL, using `http://outlook.office365.com` using OAuth2 and AD.
but when i try `https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/_api/social.feed/news` i get `401 unauthorized` error.

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to use active directory to access sharepoint 2013 news feed ?